# Is it bad form to assign a service to a controller's scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a service FooService and a controller FooController.

Let's say FooService has 3 variables (among other variables) fooA, fooB and fooC that need to show in some view.

Is it bad form in the controller to:

```
$scope.fooService = FooService;
```

And then in the view to:

```
{{ fooService.fooA }} - {{ fooService.fooB }} - {{ fooService.fooC }}
```

Or, is it best-practice to assign the variables needed by the controller and view like so:

```
$scope.fooA = FooService.fooA;
$scope.fooB = FooService.fooB;
$scope.fooC = FooService.fooC;
```

And then in the view to:

```
{{ fooA }} - {{ fooB }} - {{ fooC }}
```

I have been assigning whole services to the controllers' scopes but I feel I am doing something wrong. Is it?

Comment: Its completly ok to put the service in the scope. This way variables like `fooA` get more context when written as `FooService.fooA`.

Comment: It is perfectly fine and a good way to use when we need the updated values changed in one controller to an entirely different controller

Comment: It is considered good practice to have structured variables in the Scope. This way you can see the relationship between the variables. Like `customer.name`, `customer.email` insteed of `name` and `email`.

Comment: phylax, why comment and not answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to inject the service in the Controller and work with it

```
function Controller($scope, ServiceA, ServiceB, ...) {
var bar = ServiceA.doFoo();
...
}
```

But anyway... Controller should consume Service, etc.